# Program in C does not execute as desired (when an Int is entered followed by a char)

Tags: c

In my code below in C, I wonder why it does't work when I prompt (ask) the user to enter firstly an `int` then followed by `char`, as I think it should?

The following is my code:

```
void square(int side, char fillCharacter);

int main() {
    int inputVal;
    char inputChar;

    printf("Enter side value: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputVal);

    printf("Enter any character: ");
    scanf("%c", &inputChar);

    square(inputVal, inputChar);
    return 0;
}

void square(int side, char fillCharacter) {
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 1; i <= side; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 1; j <= side; j++) {
            printf("%c", fillCharacter);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `"%c"` format specifier matches white space characters and the `"%d"` specifier leaves the trailing `'\n'` inserted when you pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>, so you need to instruct `scanf()` to ignore white space characters with the `"%c"` specifier by explicitly adding a white space in front of the specifier like this

```
scanf(" %c", &inputChar);
/*     ^_ explicit white space here */
```

read [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)'s, linux manual page and search for the `"%c"` specifier to see what I mean.

Comment: Or by adding a space after %d I would suppose =)

Comment: @Segmented No, adding a space after `"%d"` doesn't work, because the problem is the `"%c"` specifier as you can see from the manual.

Comment: One could argue that user input which is whitespace separated should be read with whitespace-ignoring format specifiers, here `%s`, perhaps `%1s`. Although I would also assume that additional input without intervening whitespace would be an error and should be discarded, i.e. read into the array and forgotten. (Or, better, cause a warning or error.)

Comment: @iharob Yes but the FILE is the same (stdin), so it should be equivalent.

Comment: @iharob I just tested, it works either way as I predicted. =)